# Can I power A/C and furanance from two different services?

Tags: hvac, furnace

[I combined a duplex (with separate electric service) into a single unit. It still has two electric services and they're small.]

I learned from another question that I should not try to merge two different main services from the power company into one panel.

So I tried to reallocate my AC to the other power panel for the other service. The AC won't turn on after that. Do I need to move the furnace to the same power panel? Any other possible reason the furnace won't turn on? It used to work just fine, before I moved the AC power line to a different power panel.

Comment: What the difference is power panels?  Is this a separate service?  Why does the circuit need to be moved?  Be careful, it sounds like you are into things you know just enough to make you really dangerous.

Comment: @Tyson OP has a former duplex and two main pnels, undersized for his now-large house.

Comment: It doesn't directly answer your question, but perhaps you could contact the utility to have them "merge" the services so you have a single hookup. Sounds like an opportunity to upgrade your panel too (which @Harper quite likes)

Comment: Is the service feeding the panel on?

Comment: Thanks @Harper! It makes so much sense after your editing. =) Yes. I have to open two accounts with power company in order to keep all the service.

Comment: What does "tried to reallocate my AC to the other power panel" mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, air conditioning units are simple things.  They have

- a freon hose in and out
- 240V electric power which runs the compressor
- a 24V signal wire which operates a big contactor that turns e A/C unit on.

In this case, the furnace and the A/C unit are connected only by the freon hoses and the 24V thermostat line.  There is no mains AC power connection.  The furnace does not care where the A/C unit gets its power, it could come off a diesel engine and it wouldn't care.

The 24V control power is generated by the furnace using a transformer, from *its* mains power supply.  However the 24V is its own totally separate *service*; it doesn't care which service the A/C unit is on.

So... I think your problem is somewhere else.  I think that electricity isn't getting to the A/C unit, you didn't turn a breaker on, you disconnected the thermostat wire, etc.

### Or not...

If your air conditioning unit is not like I describe here, then that may be a problem.  There are some modern units that do some more complicated things. *Fine then, so what?* The fact is, a furnace unit draws fairly little electricity - only a few hundred watts for the fan to blow air around.  So the furnace adds fairly little load to the panel and it doesn't really need to be on a separate service in your case.

*Oh wait, your heat is electric? (Or heat pump with aux heat)*. Yes, electric heat is a very big load indeed. But like the air conditioner is supposed to be, the huge heating elements are contactor controlled, and are electrically very simple, and could be powered from a different service.

Comment: Fortunately the unit is forced air, not heat pump. I hate heat pump. =) I will check it more carefully to see if I can figure it out. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It should work just fine. Did you check that you have 240 volts at the contractor?  Make sure you have it connected to L1 and L2. If you used 2 half breakers instead of 2 whole breakers then both lines would be coming from either L1 or L2 which is a 120volt circuit. The only way to use half breakers is to use what is called a quad breaker which has 4 breakers. The two outer ones or the two inner ones would be used to make a 240volt circuit the other two are used either separately for 120volt or combined for another 240 volt circuit . I have seen this mistake more than once.